# How important is HDR when using an Xbox One X on a 4K TV that doesn't support HDR?

Tags: xbox-one, monitor

Ok,  so I bought an Xbox One X for use on my Samsung 4K TV only to find out that my TV doesn't support the kind of HDR (or any kind) that the Xbox wants to output.

Does the HDR aspect of the display add enough to the experience to merit me needing to buy a new TV, or is the addition not that noticeable?

I agree that this might be opinion based, but I'm really wanting to know whether it was largely a pointless exercise buying the One X when using a non HDR TV.

My TV is a Samsung UE55HU7500 with a Samsung Evolution Kit attached. There’s no HDR mentioned in the TVs menus anywhere. From what I read online, the panel won’t support HDR.

What I see on the Xbox setting screen is

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't call it "largely" pointless - you still have the ability to play a bunch of games in 4k. Reputedly HDR is much more noticeable than 4k... you are definitely missing out, but by what degree is really impossible to say.

Comment: I'm curious what TV you have. I have a samsung and it was a bit of a fiddle to get it set up to use HDR so I just want to check that you are absolutely sure that your TV and Xbox don't talk HDR to each other. My reading is that the TV does HDR but that you think it is the "wrong type"? or have I misread that?

Comment: @Chris Thanks, I’ve updated my question with this new information.

Comment: @Snow: Ah, yes. Looks like that has 3d but no HDR. The reason I wanted to check is because I spent ages trying to set up my UHD/HDR (and at one point having my shiny new xbox one x displaying in 480 resolution. It wasn't quite as plug and play as I'd expected. Anyway, for your question its really hard to say. I suspect you won't get many answers because I suspect very few people will have played in 4k with and without HDR to be able to offer an expert opinion. You'll still be getting benefits though so it definitely isn't a waste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't answer the "is it better" question, but we can say **what is different** with and without HDR. Here are some comparison shots.

[image]
Tomb Raider

[image]
Uncharted 4

It seems like there's a pretty significant difference in color depth.

More information and source [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.businessinsider.com/what-hdr-games-look-like-on-xbox-one-s-2016-8).